# How am i getting comments on my Wordpress Website, when there is no comment box on the pages

Tags: wordpress, comments, wp-admin

so this is one page in question - https://www.plasticcreditexchange.com/un-plastic-pollution-treaty/

[image: and this is the comment that i received on the post here]

I can see this and other comments on 'Comments' in wpadmin left side menu - but on the website itself i cannot see - how and from where these comments are being posted on the website

noob here - so im thinking maybe it is hack of somekind